# how to put source command in .cshrc file with arugment

Tags: tcsh

I am trying to put a source command in my .cshrc file with an argument at the end, but its not working. The command is below (it works when i run in on the terminal, just not from the .cshrc file). how should i get it to work?
I have tried putting the command in brackets and ""s I have also tried the bottom code.

```
source  /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/bin/compilervars.csh ia32
```

when i source my .cshrc file i get `setenv: Too many arguments.`

```
set INTEL = (ia32)
source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/bin/compilervars.csh $INTEL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
set INTEL = (ia32)
```

This will make a list, rather than a string variable.

[From reading the Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-compilers-for-linux-with-ubuntu) – which I found with a 10-second internet search – it seems you almost certainly want:

```
set INTEL = ia32
```

It's also possible that the `$INTEL` variable is used by the `compilervars.csh` script, so if that doesn't fix it try renaming it.